# OpenVPN Redirection works exept for Server

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

my problem is of the following. I installed and configured a OpenVPN server in my university network and as far as i can see it works fine, exept that every connection I try to establish to the server (over the redirected vpn) never goes through the vpn. The openVPN redirection setup works with NAT which should work properly.
I need to connect to a licensing server which is installed on the same machine the openVPN is on.

The server config is:

```
local <server ip>
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\server-keys\\dh1024.pem"
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\server-keys\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\server-keys\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\server-keys\\server.key" 

topology subnet

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 

push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"


push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option <dns university>"

keepalive 10 120

comp-lzo

status "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn-status.log"
log "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
log-append "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
verb 3
```

The client config is:

```
client

dev tun

proto udp
remote <server ip> 1194         
nobind 
push "redirect-gateway def1"

keepalive 10 900
inactive 3600
comp-lzo


verb 3

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\client.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\client.key"
```

Does anyone has a clue why the redirect works for every ip except the ip of my server? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`push "redirect-gateway def1"` is working as it should. When `push "redirect-gateway def1"` is encountered by an VPN client, it will set two routing rules.

```
Rule 1: Forward all traffic to `OpenVPN Server Public IP` using the current default gateway

Rule 2: Forward all other traffic through OpenVPN Server
```

Probably the problem you are encountering is because of rule number 1. If you access the OpenVPN server using its VPN IP address, you will got through the OpenVPN tunnel.

On the other hand, if you access OpenVPN server using it's public IP address, you will go through the default gateway of your router.

You can make license server to listen on 10.8.0.1 (VPN Interface IP) and reconfigure the clients to use 10.8.0.1 as license server IP address. The success of this workaround depends on how your license server setup.

Comment: So far thank you very much for the answer :). Is there a way to circumvent that? except using another network interface.

Comment: Added a workaround in answer.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks again :)

Comment: What about Android? The same config file on Android redirect the traffic of the public IP server as well.